# How to calculate the distance of multiple points to a line in QGIS

Tags: qgis, distance, regression

I'd like to do a regression analysis of magnetic susceptibility measurements taken at several sample points to a nearby road. The purpose is to see if proximity to the road correlates with higher magnetic susceptibility. For this to work I need to know how far each point is from the road. I've added a vector line over the road to provide something to measure against. Can anyone recommend how I should proceed from here. Ideally I'd like something that will measure all of the points en mass as it would be tedious to measure each one individually. I tried the distance matrix but it can only measure the relationship between points, not between points and a line.

Answer (score 2):

Your measurements are a point layer, if I understood correctly. Create a new attribute on this layer with Field Calculator with this expression and replace `line_layer` with the name of the line layer. The expression looks for each point which is the nearest line on the layer `line_layer`, then identifies the cosest point on this line and returns the length measurement to the current point:

```
distance(
    $geometry,
    closest_point(
        overlay_nearest ('Output least cost path',$geometry)[0],
        $geometry
    )
)
```